# echo all coloumn name and all rows dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rows

Yo brothers, I am trying to echo all data from a table including column names and fields. I am able to successfully get the column names, I also want to get all the rows and fields, I am not sure if I am taking the right approach to solve my issue, please help.

```
//this is to echo coloumn names
$table = '<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" style="width:60%">';
$table2 = "</table>";
$sql2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tablename";
$query2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
$tablename = $_POST['db'];
echo $table;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
echo $row[0] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
echo $table2 . "<br /><br />";
// successful in echoing coloumn names

// now i want to echo rows based on the number of coloumns
$countcol = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

echo $table;
$i = "";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
for($i=0;$1<$countcol;$i++){
echo $row[0];
}
}
echo $table2 . "<br /><br />";
// this doenst get the all the rows based on the no of coloumns
```

Comment: I see that you are building the <table> but I'm not seeing the <tr> </tr> for every row and the <td></td> for every cell.

Comment: oh .. that i havent mentioned here ... just wanted to keep the code easy to understand @satchcoder

Comment: Ook, soo in the final loop, is the echo $row[0] correct or should it be $row[$i] ?

Comment: dude .. that resolved it man .. thanks brother ;) why dont you put that as a solution and i'll accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the final loop, is the echo $row[0] correct or should it be $row[$i]